# How to access Prism.ioc container from a view model?

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, prism

I am rewriting a project that uses MVVMLight which uses ServiceLocation by Microsoft as a container into a Prism application.

This is the following code I am trying to rewrite in my view model.

```
var class = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IClass>();
```

I know that this is how you would resolve an interface using Prism.

```
var class = (iClass)containerRegistry.GetContainer().Resolve< iClass >();
```

My question is how do you resolve an interface in a viewModel using interface if you don't have access to the container?

Comment: You do not want to use the container in your view model. Take the chance and remove the design flaw that is the service locator instead of replicating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a property called Register in the IContainerRegistry in the RegisterTypes override you only have to register there your interface and your class

```
containerRegistry.Register<IYourClass, YourClass>();
```

to get access in your view model you have to add the interface as parameter

```
protected IYourClass _yourClass;
public LoginPageViewModel(IYourClass yourClass)
{
    _yourClass = yourClass;

}
```

Comment: or a `Func<IYourClass>` in case you want to create instances on the fly. Or a `IYourClassFactory` in case `YourClass` requires actual constructor parameters and not just dependencies.